# Xcode 15 - autocomplete defaulting to FALSE instead of false (and TRUE instead of true)

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I've poked around in various settings, and I don't want to start changing underlying Swift sources, but this is driving me crazy. I can't find a way to change/disable this.

Declaring a new boolean variable and typing out the initial value, autocomplete is now (since updating to Xcode 15) defaulting to all-caps versions of true and false (see image below), so when hitting enter during the auto complete phase of typing a thing, I get the wrong value.

These are defined in CFBase.h... which I am **NOT** importing anywhere in my project, and this hasn't been a thing until this latest update.

```
    #define TRUE    1
#endif

#if !defined(FALSE)
    #define FALSE   0
#endif
```

Clearly I don't want to take those declarations out, but reversing the priority order in auto-complete so that "false" and "true" come before "FALSE" and "TRUE" respectively would be awesome.

Thoughts?

Note: Yes, it's possible to hit space after typing the word and THEN hitting enter to skip this issue, but ya know... inefficient and stupid. :)

[image: Image capturing the auto-complete issue]

Comment: Don't import `CFBase.h` into a Swift project then. You can't change how Xcode does its thing.

Comment: Well, I'm not. Perhaps some library I'm using is, but I'm not expressly importing it. That's not the issue... or at least not an obvious solution. I was just showing where they're defined for clarity and completeness.

Comment: And to further clarify - this is the case even if I start a brand new Xcode project and literally just define a boolean, and has only been since updating.

Comment: I'm running Xcode 15.0 and just tried it, and I get `false` (lower case) as expected. I'm not sure why your Xcode has reverted to Objective-C conventions on you.

Comment: Currently I just found that using ctrl-z after xCode choose TRUE/FALSEwill get the correct writing in lowercase.

Comment: I'm noticing the same the for the past few days and it's driving me crazy (using XCode 15.0)

Comment: 3 out of 4 respondents = 75% global problem! #science :) 

But seriously, this is rather maddening. Much 'net research has yielded lots of the same complaint, but no actual explanation or ability to change it (back?). (sigh)